# Display a message using msg in PHP

Tags: php

I have to redirect a to a page and say x already exist.

I am doing some think like this:

```
header('location:newcategory.php'?msg=category exists);
```

I would prefer to do this from PHP, rather than in JavaScript.

Comment: I think it's header('Location: newcategory.php?msg='.urlencode('category exists'));

Comment: This question is really unclear, can you please edit and clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the page doing the redirecting:

```
header("Location: newcategory.php?msg=" . urlencode('category exists'));
```

On the newcategory.php page:

```
echo $_GET['msg'];
```

Comment: Gah! you always get there just a few seconds before me. I've seen you a number of times in the past few days.

Comment: I've had too much free time the past few days.

Comment: This is use to check duplication of data so if the data is already present it got to that page and display the error but if it is not present it should get in and it should redirect to other page but i m not able to use header again so, any solution.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Why are you unable to use header to redirect?

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: :newcategory.php?msg=category exists&var=".$x);
```

in the newcategory.php add this

```
if(msg == "category exists")
{
   echo $var." already exists";
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought too, but in terms of SEO it's better that they be redirected.

Comment: I did this, it is working but i want that msg in the page not in the address bar header('location:newcategory.php?msg=category exists');

Answer (score 0):

It won't be good if you pass whole message in a GET parameter, as it would be probably vulnerable to some sort of XSS. The best way is to store collection of message and their identifiers and produce message on the fly. For example you could have an array:

```
$messages = array(
'exists' => 'category %s exists',
'failed' => 'query %s failed'
);
```

And then pass only message identifier in an URL, optional is parameter defining more clearly what happened:

```
header("Location: newcategory.php?msg=exists&id=2");
```

In target page you could write something like that:

```
$msg = '';
switch($_GET['msg'])
    {
    case 'exists':
        {
        $msg = sprintf($messages[$_GET['msg']], intval($_GET['id']));
        break;
        }
    }
echo $msg;
```

It could be also wrapped in some classes, but I'd shown you the idea, hope it helps.